# How to convert a long form table to wide form table in Excel?

Tags: excel, function

A picture is worth a thousand words. Let's say in one sheet I have the following table:

[image]

Using this information, I want to programatically generate the table like this(sort of un-melting the long table into the wide form) in another sheet:

[image]

How can you achieve this?

Comment: @A.S.H I don't think it's a bad question. I asked the question because I am not an excel expert. I can do this in R in a second, but was curious if it can be done in "excel" as efficiently as I was working with the excel spreadsheet.

Comment: When I commented I did not notice that this was a very old post, revived because of a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using VBA:**

```
Range("G1:K99").Clear
For Each xx In Range("A:A")
    If xx.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    Range("G1").Offset(xx.Value, 0) = xx.Value
    For e = 1 To 99
        If Range("G1").Offset(xx.Value, e) = "" Then
            Range("G1").Offset(xx.Value, e) = xx.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

The table it's created from column "G". If you want another sheet:

```
Sheets(2).Range("G1: ...
```

add the Sheets before ...
**Without VBA, following the scheme:**

[image]

Adding the formulas:

```
M2 -> =IFERROR(MATCH(L2;$A$1:$A$8;);"")
N2 -> =IFERROR(MATCH(L2;INDIRECT("$A" & (M2+1) & ":$A$8");)+M2;"")
O2 -> =IFERROR(MATCH(L2;INDIRECT("$A" & (N2+1) & ":$A$8");)+N2;"")
P2 -> =IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$8;M2);"")          Autocomplete also columns to R
```

and Autocomplete ...

Answer (score 1):

I can see another approach as well. Add two columns Count and Key.

[image: Example]

Add the formulas and expand:

```
C2 -> =COUNTIF($B$2:B2;B2)
D2 -> =B2&"|"&C2
G2 -> =IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A;MATCH($F2&"|"&COLUMN(A1);$D:$D;0));"")
```