# How to convert a long form table to wide form table in excel? - Answer not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have the exactly same problem like this here:

[How to convert a long form table to wide form table in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24423747/3581372)

But the only answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24424637/3581372)is not working. Both the VBA and the formula part (I need at least one working solution).

---

**Using VBA:**

```
Range("G1:K99").Clear
For Each xx In Range("A:A")
    If xx.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    Range("G1").Offset(xx.Value, 0) = xx.Value
    For e = 1 To 99
        If Range("G1").Offset(xx.Value, e) = "" Then
            Range("G1").Offset(xx.Value, e) = xx.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

The table it's created from column "G"

**Without VBA**, following the scheme:

Adding the formulas:

M2 -> `=IFERROR(MATCH(L2;$A$1:$A$8;);"")`
N2 -> `=IFERROR(MATCH(L2;INDIRECT("$A" & (M2+1) & ":$A$8");)+M2;"")`
O2 -> `=IFERROR(MATCH(L2;INDIRECT("$A" & (N2+1) & ":$A$8");)+N2;"")`
P2 -> `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$8;M2);"")`

Autocomplete also columns to R

and Autocomplete ...

---

I am working with Excel 2010. Can anyone check the solution?

Comment: Include your problem description right after the link to the previous question, include a screenshot and the code you tried, and we'll try to help you finishing it! ;)

Comment: I've posted [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34225780/2548351) to the question you referenced. See if you can make that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this (tested):

```
Sub test()
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim cl As Range, i&, k, x%, z%
    Dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    i = [B:B].Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    For Each cl In Range([B2], Cells(i, "B"))
        If Not Dic.exists(cl.Value2) Then
            Dic.Add cl.Value2, "1|" & cl.Offset(, -1).Value2
        Else
            x = Split(Dic(cl.Value2), "|")(0)
            z = x + 1
            Dic(cl.Value2) = Replace(Dic(cl.Value2), x, z) & _
                                    "|" & cl.Offset(, -1).Value2
        End If
    Next cl
    Workbooks.Add
    [A1] = "Room": [B1] = "Count": i = 2
    For Each k In Dic
        Cells(i, "A") = k
        Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, Split(Dic(k), "|")(0) + 2)) = Split(Dic(k), "|")
        i = i + 1
    Next k
End Sub
```

Source:

[image]

Output:

[image]