# Combining rows having same value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new to working with excel and want to know if the following is possible.

I have a file in the following format

```
R1     R2
200    A
201    A
202    A
202    A
203    A
205    B
203    B
202    B
202    C
203    C
```

and I want to convert the data as following:

```
R1                 R2
200,201,202,203    A
205,203,202        B
202,203            C
```

Please let me know if the above can be done in excel.

Thank You.

Comment: Is column R2 always sorted?  Do you have Office 365 Excel?  If the answer no to both you will need vba.

Comment: Duplicate. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423747/how-to-convert-a-long-form-table-to-wide-form-table-in-excel#24424637

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your data in columns **A** and **B**, this short macro:

```
Sub ReOrg()
    Dim nA As Long, nD As Long, i As Long, rc As Long
    Dim s As String, j As Long

    Range("B:B").Copy Range("D1")
    Range("A1").Copy Range("C1")
    Range("D:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    rc = Rows.Count
    nA = Cells(rc, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    nD = Cells(rc, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To nD
        v = Cells(i, 4)
        v2 = ""
        For j = 2 To nA
            If v = Cells(j, 2) Then
                v2 = v2 & "," & Cells(j, 1)
            End If
        Next j
        Cells(i, 3) = Mid(v2, 2)
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]